# Displaying a random image in Corona

Tags: image, random, lua, coronasdk

I have a problem that the random image isn't random. The same ball keeps being displayed?
What am I doing wrong? Its driving me crazy..

```
local ballImages ={
    display.newImage("ball1.png"),
    display.newImage("ball2.png"),
    display.newImage("ball3.png"),
    display.newImage("ball4.png"),
    display.newImage("ball5.png"),
    display.newImage("ball6.png"),
    display.newImage("ball7.png"),
    display.newImage("ball8.png")
}
local ballImages = ballImages[math.random(#ballImages)]
randomImage = display.newImage(ballImages)
```

I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the same ball being displayed every time you restart your app, or when executing the last 2 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a problem. The correct code is:

```
local ballImages ={
    display.newImage("ball1.png"),
    display.newImage("ball2.png"),
    display.newImage("ball3.png"),
    display.newImage("ball4.png"),
    display.newImage("ball5.png"),
    display.newImage("ball6.png"),
    display.newImage("ball7.png"),
    display.newImage("ball8.png")
}
local randomImage = ballImages[math.random(#ballImages)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your main.lua, so every time you run your aplication the pseudorandom generator will produce different sequences of numbers.

```
math.randomseed( os.time() )
```

Link to Corona Docs: [randomseed function](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/math/randomseed.html)